# Error when debug the release build

Tags: objective-c, ios, release, libxml2

Im getting a lot of errors when i change from debug to release build.All of them came from the Twitter library,but i think its because the `libxml/xmlreader` library.
The first error i get is:

```
error: libxml/xmlreader.h: No such file or directory
```

Searching ive found this

http://www.ashlux.com/wordpress/2009/10/04/compiling-mgtwitterengine-for-the-iphone-using-xcode/

but doesnt worked too.

Comment: Probably you have a critical difference in the "info" for your release vs debug build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can open the Build Settings tab for your target and see which build settings have multiple values. In fact if you go to the search bar and type `<Multiple values>` you will narrow down the list. If it has multiple values then there is a build difference between your Debug and Release builds.

You probably want to start with your header search path.